# Touch API: disable legacy windows messages

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-7, touch

I called RegisterTouchWindow for my form, now I'm getting the raw WM_TOUCH messages, but these messages also generate WM_MOUSEDOWN, WM_MOUSEMOVE and WM_MOUSEUP. Is there a way to disable this behavior? I only want to get the WM_TOUCH messages.

I know there is a [workaround](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd693088%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for this but I'm interested if there are any other solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your control could override WndProc like this:

```
    const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201;
    const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x202;
    const int WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x200;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDOWN 
           || m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONUP 
           || m.Msg == WM_MOUSEMOVE) 
            return;
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

If your app completely want's to ignore those messages do something like [shown here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Windows/InstallingaMessageFilter.htm)

```
public class MouseMessageFilter : IMessageFilter
{
    const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201;
    const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x202;
    const int WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x200;

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)  return true;
        if (m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONUP)    return true;
        if (m.Msg == WM_MOUSEMOVE)    return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

in main :

```
Application.AddMessageFilter(new MouseMessageFilter());
```

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this solution. You can also check if the mouse message was generated by touch and discard it, so you doesn't disable them generally. It works for almost every mouse message but not for WM_MOUSELEAVE, [I posted this in the MSDN forums.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tabletandtouch/thread/c8625e10-2cce-4c43-9a95-118616a5a82c) I appreciate your IMessageFilter suggestion :)